# How to get a data's from one database to other database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, sql-server-2000

Using SQL 2000, SQL 2005

```
Old Database Name is – Sysdatabase
New Database Name is - Dual_Proone, Dual_Protwo
```

In the above two database table name and column name are different, but values are same.

For Example

```
Sysdatabase (Database Name)

Person (Table Name)

Column Names and values are

ID Date 

001 23-02-2009
002 24-02-2009
```

So on…,

```
Company (Table Name)

Column Names and Values are

Code Name

1001 Micorsoft
1002 Dell
```

So on..,

```
Dual_Proone (Database Name)

T_person (Table Name)

Column Names and values are

EmpID, Cardeventdate

001 23-02-2009
002 24-02-2009
```

So on..,

```
Dual_Protwo (Database Name)

T_Company (Table Name)

Column Names and values are

CoCode, CoName

1001 Micorsoft
1002 Dell
```

So on..,

From the above two database, Table and column are different, but values are same.

Here I want to take all the values from dual_Proone and dual_protwo to sysdatabase

My software is connecting with sysdatabase, but I need the values from dual_Proone, dual_Protwo database.

I cannot able to change the Table name and Column names in the software, I want to take a data’s from dual_Proone and dual_Protwo

Is Possible by using trigger?

Please can any one help to solve my problem

Need query Help.

Comment: How about your post your attempt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Sql Server 2005, it is possible to select from a different database useing

ServerName.DatabaseName.dbo.Table (if it is a different server, the server must be linked.)

So you can SELECT * FORM Dual_Proone.dbo.T_person as if the table was in the same database.

Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592280/trigger-to-update-data-on-another-sql-server) as well.