# Same as "Trigger to update data on another SQL Server" but in SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000, triggers

I have the same question to ask, but I'm using both **SQL 2000 Server**.

When the table1 in SQL Server 2000 gets updated/inserted/deleted, I have to update another table in SQL Server 2000. How is it possible to achieve that ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Check out: [SQL 2000 Triggers](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/1438641/SQL-Server-2000-Trigger-Enhancements.htm).

You should be able to create a SQL Triggers.

I would recommend downloading/install the SQL 2000 SP4. See [SP 4 Enhancements - See FIX 884855](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=888799) .

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer of the [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592280/trigger-to-update-data-on-another-sql-server) does not refer to any version specific features of MSSQL.

Linked servers are also supported in MSSQL 2000.

Answer (score 0):

That's what triggers are for, so yes you can do that. The biggest thing to remember if you haven't written a trigger before is that the trigger fires on the whole batch nor row-by-row, so all code to insert to another table must be set-based not row-based.

To be more specifc as to the code code  you need to write the trigger we would need more details as to waht you want to do. Are you creating an audit table? Are you creating a child record? PLease show the details of data going into table1 and what data you would expect the trigger to put into table2 as a result.