# Linking SQL Server 2000 and SQL Server 2008, is this possible?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am writing stored procs for a new system in SQL Server 2008 but I need to also update data in an older db - SQL Server 2000.  I have searched but haven't found any solution to this.  Is it possible?  What are my choices?

Thank you!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trigger to update data on another sql server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/592280/trigger-to-update-data-on-another-sql-server)

Answer (score 1):

If you mean connect to and query against a SQL Server 2000 database, then yes, this is possible through the use of linked servers assuming that the two database servers are able to communicate with each other on the same network.

See [Linked Servers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279.aspx) for more.

Answer (score 0):

This has been asked and answered in another thread, but here's a great link to get you on your way:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279.aspx

The concept you're looking for is called a "linked server", which allows SQL Server to send SQL commands to a remote server.