# SQL Server: Synchronizing Legacy and New Database Tables

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server, triggers

We have a database [NDB] which has migrated records from legacy database [LDB].  Tables in [NDB] has columns in the tables in [LDB] and some new columns. However the column naming standard is different in [NDB]. The prefix “tlb” is removed from table names in [NDB] as well as underscores are removed from column names in [NDB].

The [NDB] is loaded using SSIS with [LDB] as the source. The [NDB] is SQL Server 2008 whereas [LDB] is SQL Server 2000

There were two applications using legacy DB [LDB]. 1) Scheduling 2) Invoicing. We are moving the (new version of ) Scheduling application over to new database [NDB].  However the invoicing application will remain in [LDB].

There are some tables used by both of these applications( E.g. tblMyTable).  When tblMyTable is updated by Invoicing application, the “MyTable” in [NDB] also should be updated.

I cannot use log shipping since the table and column names are not same.

I tried with CLR Trigger and got burned myself. These tables have identity columns. Suppose there happens an exception in invoicing application (which is connected to legacy database [LDB]) during insertion into tblMyTable. The insertion does not happen; however the identity seed value is increased. During the next insert the data in tblMyTable and MyTable will be out of sync.

Note: There are no CreatedDate/CreatedBy/LastModifiedBy/LastModifiedDate columns in tables in legacy db [LDB].

So, what is the best solution to adopt here?

---

READING:

1. [Trigger to update data on another sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592280/trigger-to-update-data-on-another-sql-server)

Comment: Does the LDB need to be constantly synchronized with the NDB?  If the invoice application is the only application running off of the LDB, can is function with data from yesterday?

Comment: I had the question in mind. Client need to decide that. Our clinet will accept only if we prove that there is no alternative. Anyhow, what will be the solution?

Comment: The more I think on it the more of a mess it is.  It might be faster to just repoint the invoicing application to the NDB (less effort).

Comment: Thanks for taking pain to think about it. Pointing the invoicing app to NDB is not at all feasible from the clients point of view.

Comment: Is the invoicing app a custom application?  If there really isn't that much of a table structure change it shouldn't be that difficult and it represents less risk then trying to keep the two databases up to date.

Comment: Can you use views and/or synonyms in NDB to make it look exactly like LDB to the invoicing application? What control over the application do you have? Can you change it or not? If you can't, porting to a completely new database schema is almost certain to fail anyway. And why bother with a new database schema if it causes so many problems?