# Update table (target) from different database (source)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL Server instance running on my machine.

It has 2 databases:

1. `SF_PROD`
2. `SF_INIT`.

`SF_PROD` and `SF_INIT` have a common table `USER_MASTER` with the same structure.

My requirement is that whenever `SF_PROD.USER_MASTER` gets updated, the same operation should be applied to `SF_INIT.USER_MASTER`.

Is there any way to accomplish this task?

Comment: You just need a table trigger, if both the databases are on the same sql server instance.

Comment: Maybe your problem just like in this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592280/trigger-to-update-data-on-another-sql-server

Comment: @SudiptaMondal : Yes both dbs are in same instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both databases are running on the same SQL Server Instance, then you can just write [Trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) on `SF_PROD.USER_MASTER` which inserts the data into `SF_INIT.USER_MASTER` table.

```
CREATE TRIGGER SyncUserMasterTrigger ON SF_PROD.USER_MASTER 
FOR INSERT
AS
INSERT INTO SF_INIT.USER_MASTER  (col1, col2 , col3)
SELECT  col1 , col2 , col3
FROM inserted
```

Comment: @vishnudas you can write the trigger for `Update` as well.